# How to change the background of an image with transparent pixels?

Tags: language-agnostic, graphics, background-color, antialiasing

The exact background color is known.

Imagine an anti-aliased font on a green background. Now we want to change the background color of the image to red.

So.. How do I extract the "non-background" portion of the color from the pixel and add it (or "blend") on top of another bg color afterwards?

We also know the font color, so we know which pixels are fully opaque.

Comment: It would seem the answer will depend on language and how you want to make the change. For example, do you want to change it real-time, right after it is downloaded to a page? Or just use photoshop and change it one time? In my WPF app, will the background change based on how the application feels (no errors, it is green, lots of errors, angry red :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every pixel in the image is either the background color, the font color, or some blend of the two. So you could specify the whole image with the background RGB values, the font RGB values, and an array of values between 0 and 1, where, say, 0 means the pixel is the background color, 1 means the pixel is the font color. A value like 0.1 means that the pixel is mostly background color with a little font color, etc.

An expression like:

```
blend_value = ((pixel.R - bg.R) / (font.R - bg.R)
              + (pixel.G - bg.G) / (font.G - bg.G)
              + (pixel.B - bg.B) / (font.B - bg.B)) / 3
```

will give you these values for any pixel in the image. To construct the new RGB values using a new background color, you use this value to blend the font color with the new background color.

```
new_pixel.R = blend_value * font.R + (1 - blend_value) * new_bg.R
new_pixel.G = blend_value * font.G + (1 - blend_value) * new_bg.G
new_pixel.B = blend_value * font.B + (1 - blend_value) * new_bg.B
```